# How to enable LDAP with PHP 7.0 in Ubuntu server?

Tags: php, ldap

I have recently upgraded Ubuntu to version 16.04 and PHP to version 7. However, the ldap connection is not working.

How to enable ldap in PHP 7?

Comment: Is the LDAP-Extension available and enabled in PHP? Do you see ```ldap``` being mentioned in a ```phpinfo```-output?

For me it looks like PHP is not available. But from that little information I can'T really say anything more

Answer (score 57, accepted):

To install ldap on a lamp with PHP version 7.0 (or 7.1):

- `apt-get install php7.0-ldap` (or use `apt-get install php7.1-ldap` )
- `service apache2 restart`
- After that create a php file to get the php configuration phpinfo();
- Now ldap is installed.

Comment: Perfect! Got dokuwiki working with authad extension now.

Comment: To install ldap on a lamp with PHP version 7.1 `apt-get install php7.1-ldap`

Comment: I was missing the apache restart

Comment: I was trying this for a while on a docker container before finding that it needs something completely different, which worked perfectly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59859826/9587457

Answer (score 47):

Providing the php version number is no more required:

```
apt-get install php-ldap
```

Is enough now, the correct package version will be automatically installed.

**PS**: Note that is it true if you use the standard php packages provided by your distribution. If you are using an additional ppa for PHP like the [sury one](https://deb.sury.org/), you will have to specify the version number as there are multiple versions available.

Comment: This one works if you have the latest PHP installed. :) I needed one for a previous version. +1 for a good answer!

Answer (score 3):

install both php ldap for your specific php version, mine was

```
sudo apt install php7.2-ldap php-ldap -y
```

it solves the problem i was having