# Composer ldap extension issue

Tags: php, ldap, composer-php

When i run composer `install` in my working directory i get:

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for tiesa/ldap 1.0.x-dev -> satisfiable by tiesa/ldap[1.0.x-dev].
    - tiesa/ldap 1.0.x-dev requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
```

I succesfully installed ldap extension on Ubuntu with `apt-get install php5.6-ldap`.

After apache2 restart i have ldap listed in `phpinfo()`, but Composer error remains same.

[image]

What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe `ldap` extension is disabled for `cli` ?

Comment: @maximkou Thanks for answer. I just realized i have to install ldap extension for php which composer use. So I installed php7-ldap and it's working fine.

Comment: This answer worked for me. [How to enable LDAP with PHP 7.0 in Ubuntu server?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40748823/7519779)