# Use ldap inside of Docker-container

Tags: php, docker, ldap, docker-container

I have 2 docker containers. Inside of the first docker-container is my lamp application with php-7.3.4, apache2 ; inside of the second one is mysql database.

I've tried to connect ldap server inside first container. I proceed to the 'test-project' folder and configured custom_config.inc.php

```
 $tlCfg->authentication['method'] = 'LDAP';

 $tlCfg->authentication['ldap_server'] = 'ldap.xyz.com';
 $tlCfg->authentication['ldap_port'] = '389';
 $tlCfg->authentication['ldap_version'] = '3';
 $tlCfg->authentication['ldap_root_dn'] = 'dc=xyz,dc=com';
 $tlCfg->authentication['ldap_bind_dn'] = 'uid=tl,ou=staff,dc=xyz,dc=com';
 $tlCfg->authentication['ldap_bind_passwd'] = 'XYZw';
 $tlCfg->authentication['ldap_tls'] = false; // true -> use tls
```

After I have tried to login to the webpage via ldap credentials and throwed http error 500

When I viewed logs I got:

Error: 
       https://i.stack.imgur.com/hST65.jpg

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function 
ldap_connect() in 
var/www/html/testlink/lib/functions/ldap_api.php:42\nStack trace :\n#0                     
/var/www/html/testlink/functions/ldap_api.php(165): 
ldap_connect_bind(Array)\n#1 
var/www/html/testlink/lib/functions/doAuthorize.php(200): 
ldap_authenticate('test_user', 'test')\n#2 
var/www/html/testlink/lib/functions/doAuthorize.php(90): 
auth_does_password_match(Object(tlUser), 'test')\n#3 
var/www/html/testlink/login.php(45): doAuthorize(Object(database), 
'test_user', 'test', Object(stdClass))\n#4 {main}\n thrown in 
var/www/html/testlink/lib/functions/ldap_api.php on line 42, refer: 
http://***.**.com/login.php
```

How can I configure ldap?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I think you'll get better response if you paste the log message in textual and searchable form here.

Comment: @Stein I have updates the log information, pasted the text variant

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1120247/installing-ldap-extension-docker - although make sure you use the right LDAP package for your version.

Comment: @NigelRen I didn't change the Dockerfile right now(will do it in the future because of some problems), so I did inside the container this step: apt-get install php5-ldap and got E: Package 'php5-ldap' has no installation candidate

Comment: You will probably need `php7.3-ldap` instead or try `docker-php-ext-install ldap`

Comment: @NigelRen the same result with php7.3-ldap, right now I don't want to rebuild my container. Does any variants withour rebuilding container?

Comment: @NigelRen I've tried 'docker-php-ext-install ldap' inside of my Dockerfile, but got the issue Cannot find ldap.h. returned a non-zero code: 1

Answer (score 6):

You need to put the following lines in your php Dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libldap2-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-configure ldap --with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
RUN docker-php-ext-install ldap
```

Comment: I wish I could give another 50 pluses!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

YourApache/PHP container is missing the PHP LDAP extension. You will need to either rebuild that container so that it includes the PHP LDAP extension or you need to use a Userland LDAP-library like https://packagist.org/packages/freedsx/LDAP (never used it so can't say anything about it). Beware that the Userland library uses a different API than the PHP extension, so you will need to rewrite your code. So in the end rebuilding your container can be the easier solution.

Comment: I need to use the first one PHP LDAP extension inside my container, but when I tried to install it with `docker-php-ext-install ldap` inside of my Dockerfile I got an issue: **Can not find ldap.h**

Comment: You probably need to install openldap in the container as well - probably the openldap-dev package as well. The PHP LDAP extension is merely a wrapper to whatever LDAP client is used underneath (usually openldap but f. e. Microsofts own implementation on windows). For an example have a look at https://github.com/heiglandreas/authLdap/blob/master/dockersetup/Dockerfile_wordpress