# Installing/Enabling PHP LDAP on Debian Linux Server for Apache2

Tags: php, apache, ldap, php-extension

I am running a Debian Linux server that is hosting my Apache2 web server for an in-house web application I am developing. I am attempting to utilize LDAP for user authentication by communicating with our Active Directory server checking user info and global security groups.

On my Linux server I installed the php_ldap module using the standard apt-get:

`sudo apt-get install php-ldap`

I then modified my php.ini file to uncomment this extension:

`extension=ldap`

And add this extension:

`extension=php_ldap.so`

I have not altered my apache2.conf file yet as in my dev environment (which is unfortunately in Windows for now due to various constraints I've picked up from previous developers) the current setup works.

Besides installing the module, and enabling it in my configuration files, then lastly restarting the apache2 service on my linux server, I'm not sure what else I could be missing.

When I attempt to POST to my index.php page with the login information I get a this error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ldap_connect()...`

It is obviously not recognizing the LDAP methods I've implemented but for the life of me I cannot figure out why. All the googling I've done has led me to the same exact steps I've already outlined so if anyone has any additional information that could help me out I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I went ahead and double checked that the module was actually loaded into php by running php -m and php7.3 -m on my linux server and ldap is not showing up on the list of loaded modules despite my interaction with the config files and restarting apache.

Comment: What php version are you using for the apache2?

Comment: Could you please to check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39786114/how-to-enable-ldap-with-php-7-0-in-ubuntu-server/42250920

Comment: Dmitry I am using php 7.3.15, and unfortunately that article you shared is one of the first resources I found in trying to solve this problem myself but alas did not work, I installed the correct version via that method, placed the appropriate lines in my .ini and .conf files for php and apache both and restarted all services. But not only are the ldap commands still unrecognized but the ldap module does not show under loaded php modules for my build.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily install `LDAP` if you are using Docker.

If you don't then I would like to encourage you to start using it. Docker works on Linux and Windows as well.

[How to install Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository)

Then create a text file called Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
RUN apt-get update -y --fix-missing && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y libldb-dev libldap2-dev && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) ldap
```

in the same directory where is Dockerfile issue a command:

```sh
docker build -t my-php .
```

to see build images:

```sh
docker image ls
```

to run the image and enter shell type:

```sh
docker run --rm -it my-php:7.4-apache /bin/bash
```

once you are into shell type:

```sh
php -m
```

and you should see list of extensions including `ldap`.

type into shell

```sh
exit
```

to leave it

and you may start your web server with the command:

```sh
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name my-php-apache -v "path/to/web/dir/on/local/machine":/var/www/html php:7.4-apache
```

[How to use apache docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) - look for the section `php:<version>-apache`

If you would like to install also other extensions see the section `How to install more PHP extensions`

There are also other useful Docker images like [MySQL](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=mysql&type=image) that you may want to use as well.

Answer (score 0):

First check `phpinfo()`. When PHP had not been built with flags `--with-ldap` or `--with-ldap-sasl`, you'll have to build PHP from source, in order to get LDAP support with or without SASL.

In case it had been enabled *at build time*, then package [`php7.0-ldap`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/php7.0-ldap) should suffice. Run `dpkg -L php7.0-ldap` to see what and where it installs. If anything else may be required, then this may be `php -m` and `phpenmod ldap`.

One can apply LDAP configuration with a `/home/www-data/.ldaprc` file:
https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man5/ldap.conf.5.html

Comment: Hello Martin,

I'm mostly new to the idea of building specific environments from source code. I've stuck with package managers to install and configure whatever modules I needed at the time. That being said, as this particular PHP setup was done before my time on this project, I'm not sure whether or not this was built with the ldap flags or not. The phpinfo() page does show util_ldap under the apache2handler configuration, and ldap and ldaps under the curl protocols. I'm not sure if that is sufficient, but if it isn't; is there a way to 'rebuild' my php setup to include the ldap flags?

Comment: The build configuration is being listed in `phpinfo()`, so one can see how it had been built; when it comes from the package manager, likely it was with built with that flag. What does `php -i | grep ldap` say? Make sure it is loaded in the correct INI, the PHP which the web-server uses and the CLI commonly use different INI files.

Comment: Or when it not had been enabled, uninstall the package and [build](https://gist.github.com/tuanpmt/b3781efcaacdcd2af740) instead... PHP which comes from a package manger in most cases is build with all options (but not always)... rather rarely.

Comment: It seems based on your feed back as well as the additional research I have found that rebuild my php environment is the only solution to ensure that php ldap is enabled. I'll try to walk through that build article you posted and inform the thread here how it goes. Thank you so far for the great help Martin!

Comment: @DarrenWoodson Is there any particular reason you prefer building PHP from the source yourself instead of using one of the already build [official PHP docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) and adding one line of code to the Dockerfile to get the LDAP working?